# Submit a form without refreshing page in html, js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, page-refresh

i have a small form chat like this and i want when click submit that form will not make the page refresh.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" id="formchat" action="forum_add_1313940.xhtml">
<input name="text" id="text2" max-lenght="1000"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Gửi" id="chats" />
</form>
```

and the js

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$('#formchat').submit(function () 
{
  sendformchat(); return false; 
});
</script>
```

But when i click "Gửi", the page gonna refresh.
How to make it when click "Gửi", the page not gonna refresh ?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: pls help me and sorry if my english is bad cause i'm VietNamese people

Comment: Leroy Meijer can u show me how to do ?

Comment: can anyone show me how to do cause i'm not good in js

Comment: Have you read some tutorial in vietnamese?
http://www.izwebz.com/css/contact-form-voi-jquery-ajax-php/
http://2cweb.vn/news/php-mysql/tao-form-login-hoan-chinh-bang-ky-thuat-ajax-va-validate-jquery-12-36.html
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: this just a small js ><

Answer (score 0):

If you want asynchronous behavior, you should handle the form in an AJAX style, you can read about AJAX [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)!

here is an example using jquery on your form:

```
var form = $('#form_chat');

form.find('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.prevetDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
});
```